# How to concat the values of case statement values in a single column in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

```
select
 case
   when s.X344731='Y' then 'Property Tax Assessment'
   when s.X344732='Y' then 'Property Tax Payment'
   when s.X344733='Y' then 'Birth and Death Certificate'
   when s.X344734='Y' then ' Trade License'
   when s.X344735='Y' then ' Complaints/Grievance Redressal'
   when s.X344736='Y' then 'Water Connection'
   when s.X344737='Y' then 'Sewerage Connection'
   when s.X344738='Y' then 'Online Building Plan Approval System'    
   when s.X344739='Y' then ' Fire NOC'    
   when s.X3447310='Y' then ' NOC (Others)'    
   when s.X3447311='Y' then 'Certificates (Others)'    
   when s.X3447312='Y' then 'User Charges (water charges, parking fee, advertisement charges, electricity charges etc. )'    
   when s.X3447313='Y' then 'All of the above'    
   when s.X3447314='Y' then 'None of the above'    
   else 'Not Answered' end as municipal_services_do_you_use    
from lime_survey_988773 s 
left join lime_tokens_988773 t 
on (s.token=t.token)     
where s.submitdate is not null 
  and user_id=143561;
```

I want to concat the values of these three  'Property Tax Assessment', 'Property Tax Payment' and 'Birth and Death Certificate' it will look like this:-

```
User_id  Municipal_Services_Do_you_use                                                      State
142351   ('Property Tax Assessment', 'Property Tax Payment','Birth and Death Certificate')  Delhi
```

Comment: `s."token"` ? Do you mean `s.\`token\`` and all the other places where you incorrectly use the `"`

Comment: How many databases are you going to execute this query against? Spamming tags just makes people angry, please dont do it

Comment: @RiggsFolly, double quotes usage is correct. In Oracle, it is used when object names (columns included) contain mixed letter case. That's generally bad idea (using mixed case which require double quotes) as you always have to use them. By default, Oracle everything stores (into data dictionary) in upper case, but lets you reference everything using any letter case you want (lower, mixed, upper). Unless - as I said - if you use double quotes - then you must use correct case, enclosed into double quotes. Here, it seems that tables and columns were created using lower case - hence double quotes.

Comment: @hemant, CASE expression returns only one value. Which rule (apart from "I want") should be followed so that result looks as you'd want it to? Sample data would probably help use understand the problem so - consider posting it.

Comment: Like others have said it's hard to say what would be the best approach without seeing your data (tables involved with sample data).  I would think building a lookup table would be your best option.  Instead of throwing those case statements around you could just join into the table (I am assuming) and then apply a listagg function in oracle to concat and aggregate to the user id grain.

Comment: @Littlefoot Thansk for the info, I posted that comment because at that time the only Tag was `MySQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with concatenation operators(`||`) such as

```
SELECT user_id AS "User_id",
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.X344731='Y' THEN '(''Property Tax Assessment''' END)||
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.X344732='Y' THEN ',''Property Tax Payment''' END)||
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.X344732='Y' THEN ',''Birth and Death Certificate'')' END) 
       AS "Municipal_Services_Do_you_use"     
  FROM lime_survey_988773 s 
  LEFT JOIN lime_tokens_988773 t 
    ON t.token = s.token  
 WHERE user_id = 143561 
 GROUP BY user_id
```

would return the desired result provided that at least one `'Y'` value returns for each column with the name like `X344...` while `user_id = 143561` after joining those tables.